# Django get_model nested app and app_label

Tags: django, model, nested

I am working with code that is attempting to use my Django 1.6 extended user model.  The code attempts to get that model like this:

```
model = models.get_model(app_label, model_name)
```

The issue I believe I'm having is that my apps are nested under an 'apps' directory, like `apps.account.UserProfile`.

I believe get_model only takes the label and name, but can it handle an app label that is nested?

Comment: To answer my own question, Django seem "smart" enough to know if the app is nested or not.  So just passing `get_model('account','UserProfile')` above works.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `get_user_model()`, which was designed for this very purpose. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model):

> You should reference the user model using `django.contrib.auth.get_user_model()`. This method will return the currently active `User` model – the custom `User` model if one is specified, or `User` otherwise.

Comment: Well, first, I did not "[substitute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)" the user model, I "[extended](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)" it. And second, the above is more of my specific example, and more about how to to use the `get_model` with a nested app.

Comment: @Derek: OK, just be aware that `django.db.models.get_model()` is not part of Django's public API. Starting in 1.7, the documented way to do this will be to use `AppConfig.get_model()`. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.get_model).